# NGINX auth_request and 302 response status = 500 invalid URL prefix

Tags: nginx, proxy, authentication, redirection

I'm trying to make NGINX authenticate requests with OAuth2 server (authorization code flow) that will redirect client to the login page.
Is it possible to use auth_request directive for that?
Here is my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen ${NGINX_PORT};

    proxy_send_timeout    600;
    proxy_connect_timeout    600;
    proxy_read_timeout    600;
    send_timeout        600;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    absolute_redirect off;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    location / {
        auth_request /authn;
        gzip_static on;
        index   index.html;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @index;
    }

    location @index {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        expires 0;
        try_files /index.html =404;
    }

    location /api {
        set $target http://gateway:8030/api;
        proxy_pass http://gateway:8030/api;
    }
    location /authn {
        set $target http://gateway:8030/authn;
        proxy_pass http://gateway:8030/authn;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        recursive_error_pages on;

        error_page 301 302 303 307 308 @handle_redirect;
    }

    location @handle_redirect {
        set $redirect_url $upstream_http_location;
        proxy_pass $redirect_url;
        }
}
```

But my oauth gateway returns redirects without schema://host:port, and I get

```
invalid URL prefix in "/oauth2/authorization/gateway" while sending to client
```

Why doesn't NGINX understand that it must preserve host and port information in redirects and how can I fix that?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find any solution?